# Plotting a curve in the margin of a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the plot of a function `f`, which depends on time in a discontinuous way. More precisely, it has a particular behavior for `t1<=t<t2` and another everywhere else, like in the example below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

l1=1.
l2=5.
t1=20.
t2=50.
tf=120.
def f1(t):
    if t<t1:
        L = l1
    elif t1<=t<t2:
        L = l2
    else:
        L=l1
    g=L*t
    return g
a=np.linspace(0.,100,1000)
values1=map(f1,a)
fig1=plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(a,values1,color='red')
plt.show()
```

The plot of the pulse is the following

```
def f2(t):
    if t<t1:
        L = l1
    elif t1<=t<t2:
        L = l2
    else:
        L=l1
    return L
values2=map(f2,a)
fig2=plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(a,values2,color='blue')

plt.show()
```

I want to make a figure with the red curve as the main plot and a little inset in the top margin of the figure showing the blue curve, without any x axis or y axis, just to make the viewer understand when the change in the parameter `L` happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that subplots will do what you want. If you make  the top subplot smaller, and take the ticks/labels off it looks like its in the margins. Here's a code snippet that sets up the plot.

```
f = plt.figure()
# Make 2 subplots arranged vertically with different ratios
(ax, ax2) = f.subplots(2,1, gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[1,4]})

#remove the labels on your top subplot
ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)

ax.plot(a, f2(a))
ax2.plot(a, f1(a), 'r:') #red curve main plt

plt.show()
```

I used this code to plot a few sinusoids and it  came out as follows:

[image]

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, with the only difference that I don't want the upper curve to be boxed. T.Y. !

Comment: and I removed it using `ax.axis('off')` . T.Y.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use `inset_axes` from `mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator`

See for example: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/inset_locator_demo.html

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1.inset_locator import inset_axes

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)

# Create inset of width 1.3 inches and height 0.9 inches
# at the default upper right location
axins = inset_axes(axs, width='20%', height='20%', loc=2)
```

And then plot your data in `axins`:

```
axins.plot(data)
```

You can also switch off the ticks and labes using:

```
axins.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
axins.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
```

Comment: Great, ty. I still have two little issues: I do not want the blue curve to be boxed, and I want it to be outside the plot of the other curve, in the top margin, but if I write `loc=-1` it does not work

Comment: You can also give a tuple to loc, which will define the coordinates, e.g. (0.9, 0.9).